# how to convert current timezone date to gmtdate in magento 2?

Tags: magento2.4.0, timezone

In Magento store, it sets `America/Toronto` timezone
how to convert current date time to gmt date time,here is my current date time code

```
$currentTimeZoneTime = $this->timezone->date()->format('Y-m-d');

$gmtTime = '?'
```

Answer (score 0):

Any Magento manipulation with date (in case you need to use current date) will call native logic:

```php
$date = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$date->format($format);
```

If you want to convert store date into UTC you can use something like:

```php
$date = new \DateTime($dateInStore);
$this->timezone->convertConfigTimeToUtc($date, $format);
```

Answer (score 0):

create this model

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Timezone\LocalizedDateToUtcConverterInterface;

class UtcToDate
{
    /**
     * @var LocalizedDateToUtcConverterInterface
     */
    private $utcConverter;

    public function __construct(
        LocalizedDateToUtcConverterInterface $utcConverter
    ) {
        $this->utcConverter = $utcConverter;
    }

    /**
     * convert UTC Date
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function convertUTCdate(): string
    {
        $localDate = date('m-d-Y');
        return $this->utcConverter->convertLocalizedDateToUtc($localDate);
    }
}
```

And Get where you want

```
$utcDate = $this->convertUTCdate();
```